# Multi-steps WordPress registration : in 4 steps how to?

Tags: users, user-registration, wp-login-form

I saw in several WordPress sites up on registration that the registration process is in 3 or 4 steps.

how can i implement such process to my theme?  ie:

1. choose your role + fill in register form----> if its ok submit then go to step 2
2. profile details : user pic , some usermeta form ----< if its ok submit then go step 3
3. Preview profile before confirm ---< go to step 4 or back to step 3 to make changes.
4. registration complete success

***UPDATE***

> hi guys i have figured it out little bit,(i am using jobroller theme which has a normal a one step registration form, but it has a multiple step forms for submting jobs listing)
>   [submit job form](http://demos.appthemes.com/jobroller/submit/).
>   what i wanted is to use the same (submit job multi-steps forms) for registration form so users are obliged to fill in profile details or whatever within the same process. registration.
>   so i hacked the original registration of jobroller theme (includes/theme-login.php) and here what it gives.
>
> [theme-login.php](http://pastebin.com/cPXeCNXW)

here is the function registration  steps that replace the original `jr_register_form()`

```
function jr_registration_steps() {

// Show registration steps forms

### Prevent Caching
nocache_headers();

jr_load_form_scripts();

//global $post, $posted;
global  $posted;
$submitID = $post->ID;

$posted = array();
$errors = new WP_Error();

if (!is_user_logged_in()) :
    $step = 1; 
else :
    $step = 2;
    if (!current_user_can('can_submit_job')) : //can_submit_listing redirect to my listing
        redirect_myjobs();
    endif;
endif;

if (isset($_POST['register']) && $_POST['register']) {

    $result = jr_process_register_form( get_permalink($submitID) );

    $errors = $result['errors'];
    $posted = $result['posted'];

//}
//elseif (isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']) {

    //$errors = jr_process_login_form();

}
elseif (isset($_POST['job_submit']) && $_POST['job_submit']) {  

    $result = jr_process_submit_job_form();//jr_process_submit_user_registration_form

    $errors = $result['errors'];
    $posted = $result['posted'];

    if ($errors && sizeof($errors)>0 && $errors->get_error_code()) $step = 2; else $step = 3;

}
elseif (isset($_POST['preview_submit']) && $_POST['preview_submit']) {

    $step = 4;

    $posted = json_decode($_POST['posted']);

}
elseif (isset($_POST['confirm']) && $_POST['confirm']) {

    $step = 4;

    jr_process_confirm_job_form();//jr_process_confirm_user_registration_form

}
elseif (isset($_POST['goback']) && $_POST['goback']) {
    $posted = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['posted']), true);
}

if( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && 'newpass' == $_GET['checkemail'] )    
    $message = __('Thank you for registering! An email has been sent to you containing your password.','appthemes');

   get_template_part('header'); ?>

<div class="section">

    <div class="section_content">

        <h1><?php _e('create an Account', 'appthemes'); ?></h1>

        <?php 
            echo '<ol class="steps">';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) :
                echo '<li class="';
                if ($step==$i) echo 'current ';
                if (($step-1)==$i) echo 'previous ';
                if ($i<$step) echo 'done';
                echo '"><span class="';
                if ($i==1) echo 'first';
                if ($i==4) echo 'last';
                echo '">';
                switch ($i) :
                    case 1 : _e('Create account', 'appthemes'); break;
                    case 2 : _e('Enter Profile Details', 'appthemes'); break;
                    case 3 : _e('Preview/Profile Options', 'appthemes'); break;
                    case 4 : _e('Confirm', 'appthemes'); break;
                endswitch;
                echo '</span></li>';
            endfor;
            echo '</ol><div class="clear"></div>';

            // show the success message usually because a password has been emailed to new user
            if (isset($message) && !empty($message)) echo '<p class="success">'.$message.'</p>';

            jr_show_errors( $errors ); 

            switch ($step) :

                case 1 :
                    jr_before_step_one(); // do_action hook
                    ?>
                    <p><?php _e('You must login or create an account in order to post a job &mdash; this will enable you to view, remove, or relist your listing in the future.', 'appthemes'); ?></p>

                    <div class="col-1">
                        <?php jr_register_form( get_permalink($submitID), 'job_lister' ); ?> <!-- change job_lister to new role--->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">         
                        <?php jr_login_form( get_permalink($submitID), get_permalink($submitID) ); ?>  <!-- delete--->
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <?php                       
                    jr_after_step_one(); // do_action hook                      
                    break;
                case 2 :    
                    jr_before_step_two(); // do_action hook
                    jr_submit_job_form(); //*****jr_submit_user_registration_form();                
                    jr_after_step_two(); // do_action hook  
                    break;
                case 3 :    
                    jr_before_step_three(); // do_action hook
                    jr_preview_job_form();  //*****jr_preview_user_registration_form();
                    jr_after_step_three(); // do_action hook
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    jr_before_step_four(); // do_action hook
                    jr_confirm_job_form();  //*****jr_confirm_user_registration_form();
                    jr_after_step_four(); // do_action hook
                    break;

            endswitch;  
        ?>

    </div><!-- end section_content -->

</div><!-- end section -->

<div class="clear"></div>
```

```
 <?php if (get_option('jr_show_sidebar')!=='no') get_sidebar('submit'); ?>

 <?php 

   get_template_part('footer');

  }
```

> here what i have in  my includes/forms/register/ register-process.php

[register-process.php](http://pastebin.com/Tf9dDU6M)

please note that i have modified this at the bottom :

`// redirect
                                wp_redirect($success_redirect);
wp_redirect($success_redirect);// redirect user to dashbord when registred
exit();`

> to this code :

```
$redirect_to = !empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_POST['redirect_to'] : '?action=register&step=2';
                            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );

                            exit;
```

> in order to add `&step=2` to the url, i think you can add similar code to the other form to redirect and show correct step in url after ?action=register

i didn't finish yet hacking the code to suit it to my needs but what i suggested is a beginin and others can help modifyin or presenting better.

hope its helps you :)

Comment: Close voted as I feel this question does not have a wordpress specific knowledge requirement

Comment: @m0r7if3r Your feelings are welcome but they are not close reasons. :)

Comment: Fritids, can you link to some examples? I'd like to see these myself ( and what plugins if any I can determine they're running )

Comment: @toscho My reasoning is that multi-page forms are multi-page forms, whether they're using wordpress or anything else. Based on my reading of the question, it seems that the issue is the multi-page form, not the user registration itself. Because of this (and the fact that multi-page forms are not wordpress specific, but rather a PHP/JS issue), I feel like it is in the scope of SO more than it is in the scope of WPSE.

Comment: @m0r7if3r I don't see how this question can be answered without knowledge about the registration and profile details of WP.

Comment: @toscho agree to disagree I suppose.

Comment: hi guys please give me some time to prepare exhaustive explanation and give examples, and give some begining bit of codes.

Comment: @TomJNowell i have seen several exemples but couldn't find them right now. i can give some other exemples like this one rather than it's a bp theme [buddyboss theme sign up](http://buddyboss.com/demo/register/) *here is the result i want to reproduce but [jobroller theme submit job](http://demos.appthemes.com/jobroller/submit/). other exemples are welcomed

Comment: the question is updated... let's make it such a tutorial for others ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method of doing this would be to use the Gravity Forms plugin, it costs money, but it's well worth the investment, and quickly pays for itself in saved development time

Comment: the code i provided above works ...for my prject i can't  go for a paid plugins at the moment, but anyway can you provide some links on how to do that with gravity Forms?

Comment: Its one o the common use cases in the gravity forms docs, it's worth buying a developers license